# Expected expression in form of '_item_ in _collection_[ track by _id_]' but got

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Only getting first element as output and getting error in console while using ng-repeat:

```
Expected expression in form of '_item_ in _collection_[ track by _id_]' but got '”pm'.
```

```js
angular.module('DataCabinet')
  .controller('IdeCtrl', ['$scope', 'ProjectService', 'authentication', 'notification',  '$location', '$timeout', '$sce',
    function ($scope, ProjectService, authentication, notification, $location, $timeout, $sce) { 

      ProjectService.projectRead().then(function(data) {
          var projectArray = JSON.parse(data.data);
          console.log("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
          console.log(projectArray);
          vm["projectRead"] = projectArray;
          // vm["prModel"] = projectArray;
          console.log(vm);
        });
    }
  ]);
```

JSON data : `{"projectRead":[{"ProjectName":"W23","ProjectType":"Jupyter IPython","PythonVersion":null,"_id":"59a0af89e1fbd208fbafe2b8","ProjectCreatedInNfs":"true"},{"ProjectName":"W33","ProjectType":"Jupyter IPython","PythonVersion":null,"_id":"59a0c37b8092720b60e10493","ProjectCreatedInNfs":"true"}]}`

```html
<div ng-controller="IdeCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat= " pm in vm.projectRead ">{{pm}}</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: You are using a fancy double quote, make sure it is the proper character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `”` with `"`.